# How to build single executable binary with CMake in linux

Tags: c, cmake

for example:

```
//main.c
int main() {

}
```

I add it in CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(MyBin ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

and run `cmake path/to/mypj`, I get "CMakeFiles/MyBin.dir", How to get "bin/MyBin".

Comment: Did you consider just using `make` (that is write your own `Makefile` *without* generating it with `cmake` ....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cmake` command is equivalent to executing the `configure` script in an autotools project, you need to *make* the main target like this

```
make
```

or even

```
make MyBin
```

to *make* only *MyBin*.